# how to log specific error message in node js?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, error-handling

I am working with sql in node js Now if some error occurs executing SQL query due to the wrong query then I get an error message along with the data in the query. So is there any way where only the error message should be printed not the data along.
for eg. If the table name is incorrect in SQL query then I get an error message as `an incorrect table name` but the query with data also gets printed as part of the error message.

Please tell me how I can avoid it? Below is sql query error along with query i want to avoid printing query data

```
[Logs] :- Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'service.journal_tabe' doesn't exist
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
    at /home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/src/services/jounal.service.ts:48:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at JournalService.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/src/services/jounal.service.ts:47:16)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/ubuntu/Documents/my_project-V2/my_project-data-service/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:110:62)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE',
  errno: 1146,
  sqlMessage: "Table 'service.journal_tabe' doesn't exist",
  sqlState: '42S02',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO journal_tabe (id, businessId, journalDate, transactionId, transactionType, number,  contactId,description,accountId, amount,isReconciled, active, version) VALUES ('0d47a468-610c-4011-9012-ed9f8e6dcf07', 'b6feb1af-31ff-4b08-9545-cd5b5747e0ba', '2020-07-08 00:00:00', '98', 'Journal Entry', '4', '1', '', '131', 991, false, true, 1), ('29489e63-6b1d-49fc-b7e0-6a06696997b0', 'b6feb1af-31ff-4b08-9545-cd5b5747e0ba', '2020-07-08 00:00:00', '98', 'Journal Entry', '', '1', '', '131', -991, false, true, 1), ('04af0569-c685-45e0-bbc1-35edaa55ca3c', 'b6feb1af-31ff-4b08-9545-cd5b5747e0ba', '2020-07-08 00:00:00', '99', 'Journal Entry', '5', '2', '', '131', 505, false, true, 1), ('9d5dc24f-b2ec-4dd2-9de1-112ec2115ae4', 'b6feb1af-31ff-4b08-9545-cd5b5747e0ba', '2020-07-08 00:00:00', '99', 'Journal Entry', '', '2', '', '131', -505, false, true, 1), ('e4ab350c-3993-41d9-b911-946282c3ab96', 'b6feb1af-31ff-4b08-9545-cd5b5747e0ba', '2020-08-13 00:00:00', '96', 'Journal Entry', '2', '0', '', '131', 100, false, true, 1), ('2e9c7e16-592a-40ca-ae2f-ec2eb2b3e323', 'b6feb1af-31ff-4b08-9545-cd5b5747e0ba', '2020-08-13 00:00:00', '96', 'Journal Entry', '', '0', '', '131', -100, false, true, 1), ('aa1849d2-93b5-4066-b952-774f2521ceb6', 'b6feb1af-31ff-4b08-9545-cd5b5747e0ba', '2020-08-13 00:00:00', '97', 'Journal Entry', '3', '1', '', '131', 201, false, true, 1), ('c1b84ead-cfcd-4dcd-88fe-174188fad7ab', 'b6feb1af-31ff-4b08-9545-cd5b5747e0ba', '2020-08-13 00:00:00', '97', 'Journal Entry', '', '1', '', '131', -201, false, true, 1), ('6a757d6e-7ab2-48e
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error that is being displayed contains some properties like **code**, **errno**, **sqlMessage** etc.

Maybe you can just `console.error(yourError.sqlMessage)`